# OData read-only property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI 2.2 application with OData V4. Also I'm using EF 6.1.

In one of my entities I have a calculated property:

```cs
public class Person 
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   
   // Calculated Property - No setter
   public string FullName 
   { 
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
   }
}
```

In order to provide the calculated property to my clients,  I need to register in the OData Model

```cs
public static IEdmModel GetModel() 
{
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    
    builder.Namespace = "NavigationServices";
    builder.EntityType<Person>;
    builder.EntityType<Person>()
        .Property(a => a.FullName); // Calculated Property
        
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

---

So, when I obtain my data in the client side, every object has the Calculated property.

However, when I try to Create (POST) a new element or Update (PUT) a existing one, my action don't recognize the element and generates an error saying that it doesn't find the "set method" for the property.

I read a couple of posts about read only properties in OData (apparently not supported) but I don't find a way to use OData with calculated properties.

Some advice of how to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 12):

Now there is a soft way for doing this which is to build a contract between the client and server using annotations.

In the [Core vocabulary of the V4 standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/vocabularies/Org.OData.Core.V1.xml), there is a such term:

```
<Term Name="Computed" Type="Core.Tag" DefaultValue="true" AppliesTo="Property">
    <Annotation Term="Core.Description" String="A value for this property is generated on both insert and update"/>
</Term>
```

In Web API OData, in WebConfig.cs, you write such code to add such annotation to your property:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var model = builder.GetEdmModel() as EdmModel;
model.SetVocabularyAnnotation(
    new EdmAnnotation(model.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("People").EntityType().FindProperty("FullName"),
    new EdmTerm("Org.OData.Core.V1", "Computed", EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.Boolean),
    new EdmBooleanConstant(true)));
```

Then in your data, it'll look something like this:

```
<Annotations Target="V4Service.Models.Person/FullName">
    <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Computed" Bool="true"/>
</Annotations>
```

Through the steps above the service advertises that the `FullName` property on `Person` entity is computed by the service. Then in the controller methods for POST and PATCH requests you can have you own logic of ignoring any value sent by the client for the `FullName` property and compute your own.

I'm not sure which client you are using. If you're using [OData Client for .NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/), our support for getting annotation values will be in our next release. If you don't mind using [EdmLib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Edm/) directly, the annotation value retrieval support has already been added.

Comment: There is no support until now, besides reading the annotation into the model right?

Comment: Is there an attribute for that?

Answer (score 6):

You are right, `OData` doesn't support `read-only properties` at this time.

However, it supports `read-only entities`.

Or, you can trick `OData` by adding a `setter` which does nothing to your `property`.

```
public string FullName
{ 
    get
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
    set
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

This is how you set an `entity` as read-only:

```
public class Northwind : DataService<NorthwindEntities>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Customers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would we do this in webapi ?

Comment: I tried the trick with the empty setter. Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shivkumar I just tried this in web api and works the same way with the empty setter.

Answer (score 2):

In your entity you need a [NotMapped] data annotation:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} - {LastName}";
```

in your OData configuration:

```
builder.EntityType<Person>;
builder.StructuralTypes.First(t => t.ClrType == typeof(Person))
                .AddProperty(typeof(Person).GetProperty(nameof(Person.FullName)));
```

this way you don't need an empty setter.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a database computed property instead of a class computed property.

[This article describes EF and database computed properties.](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidPaquette/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx) One difference that I see in your sample code compared to the article is that you don't have any setter in your property. If you set your property to use Auto Accessors with a private set

```
public string FullName { 
    get;
    private set; 
}
```

Then create the column in the database as a computed column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD FullName AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
```

As an additional plus you'll be able to query against this property using odata and Linq.

Comment: The linked article does not mention OData at all.

Comment: @CarlBussema - your correct. I reworded the post so not to be misleading.